Formatting SQL Response From SQL Select in DuckDB
Everyone who uses DuckDB in the beginning will load an CSV or EXCEL file into duckdb and then run SQL queries against it to explore the data right? Well I am seeing chopped off columns, 3 of six colunms data is showing and I want to show all 6 columns data. It does show first two or three columns and the last column which is good, but not the ones in the middle. How do I do instruct it to show them all? I am running duckdb in command line and simply want to see all of the columns in the table.  I would like to wrap the output of some columns to a certain width but I want ALL columns showing. And I dont readily see from the documentation of duckdb about this. Just about .mode changes.  How can I show the data from all the columns and not just the default number of columns? A similar question was asked here: How to see all columns of of DuckDb relation while printing it using show command but its not from command line and the answers are either increasing width or changing the mode to line which produces very different output. Again I want ALL columns showing wrapped if needed. I have only six columns it should not be that difficult.

Its private data. But its not faulty data thats the issue. Its there is an default number of columns that get shown and I dont see where to adjust this. The last column of the table is always shown. It could also be a width or wrapping setting but I dont know what need to be set
